Puma crashing randomly in Ruby on Rails
Our stack:
RoR: 5.2.3
Puma 3
Ruby 2.6.3 and redis 4.0.9
Node 13.14.0 and
Mysql 5.7
Ubuntu 18.04
Puma server sometimes crashes unexpectedly with no reproducible pattern.
The error message that we were able to gather is following:

7fe97c2e1000-7fe97c47c000 r--p 00000000 103:01 12480                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive

7fe97c47c000-7fe97c481000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7fe97c485000-7fe97c486000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0

7fe97c486000-7fe97c48d000 r--s 00000000 103:01 124282                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache

7fe97c48d000-7fe97c48f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7fe97c48f000-7fe97c490000 r--p 00029000 103:01 7777                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so

7fe97c490000-7fe97c491000 rw-p 0002a000 103:01 7777                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so

7fe97c491000-7fe97c492000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7ffc1a0f7000-7ffc1a8f6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]7ffc1a9c2000-7ffc1a9c5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]

7ffc1a9c5000-7ffc1a9c7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]

ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

[NOTE]

You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.

Bug reports are welcome.

For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Things we have tried:

To try notice when these crashing occur and found to have issues when there is a high load. Our staging server crashes way less as it has fewer loads.
We have installed a monitoring software to monitor CPU, RAM usage and have found no suspicious actions
Dockerized our app but the crashings still persists.


Do you have any rails logs? Load issues can manifest themselves in many ways, memory crashes, database connection starvation, timeouts, etc.
